# svn checkout on subdirectory, which is then renamed

Tags: linux, svn

So, we probably did something we shouldn't have done, but now I wonder how this should typically be handled.

We have a large project with multiple applications which are grouped in different sub-systems. I was working on one specific application which was found in the following subdirectory:

/svnroot/subSystemName/myApp

Since I didn't need the whole SVN, I just did a checkout of that subdirectory.

Some time later, someone else figured that the name of the sub-system wasn't quite right, so he did a svn rename on the directory, so that my application is now found in:

/svnroot/subSystemNewName/myApp

As you might imagine, this causes problems because when I try to do an update for instance, it says "target path does not exist", as it's still looking for the original path.

What am I to do? Is the only solution to do a full checkout again? How should this have been handled in the first place?

PS: I'm on Linux.

Comment: If you found your answer, feel free to accept one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 2):

[svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) should do the trick. Run `svn switch <url_of_new_location> <local_checkout_dir>`

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!